# Can ZF2 escapeHTML be used for get post data?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, escaping, zend-controller

Recently I was assigned to a project and I see this in the controller:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $escapar = new Escaper('utf-8');
        $consulta = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $nombreComercial =  $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['nombreComercial']);
        $razonSocial=$escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['razonSocial']);
        $rfc = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['rfc']);
        $estado = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['estado']);
        $municipio = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['municipio']);
        $sectorprimario = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['sectorprimario']);
        $sectorsecundario = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['sectorsecundario']);
        $localidad = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['localidad']);
        $telefono = $escapar->escapeHtml($consulta['telefono']);
        $empresa = new Empresa($this->dbAdapter);

        $empresas = $empresa->searchEmpresas($nombreComercial, $razonSocial, $rfc, $estado, $municipio, $localidad, $sectorprimario, $sectorsecundario, $telefono, $identi->id_institucion);
        return $this->forward()->dispatch('Gestion\Controller\Cpanel', array('action' => 'searchpymes','nombreComercial'   => $nombreComercial, 'consulta'=>$empresas));

    }
```

Is it correct to use `escapeHTML` for to get the incoming data from the POST request?

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation we can read this :

> `Zend\Escaper` is meant to be used *only for escaping data that is to be output*, and as such should not be misused for filtering input data. For such tasks, the [Zend\Filter component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/index.html#zend-filter), [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) or PHP’s [Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) component should be used.
>
> From: [Zend Escaper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.escaper.introduction.html#what-zend-escaper-is-not)

`escapeHtml()` is one of the methods provided by the `Zend\Escaper`, so it should be used for escaping **output data**.

For input data (which is your case), you might have a look at the [Zend\Filter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html)

Comment: I also thought something like that, but i still being a begginer, thank you for your help